# How to pass huge data through ajax call using XmlHttpRequest

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I need to pass huge data to the controller. I have used `XmlHttpRequest`.
I have written the code like:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/Home/Content", true);
xmlhttp.send("content=" + data);
```

And the `ActionResult` will look like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(string content)
{
      return Json("suc", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The data will be like

```
 UklGRipkAABXRUJQVlA4[...huge piece of data...]kxgTrTkKyKe6xap+GYnY93Kj
```

But it is not passing to the controller. It is showing that data is too long. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Why are you sending the data as query param. You are using post so send the data as POST rather then query param.

Answer (score 1):

Send the data in the POST body, by passing it as an argument to `send`:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/Home/Content", true);
xmlhttp.send("content=" + data);
```

Then, on the server, read the `content` parameter of the POST data.

Comment: I have tried this but it is not passing to the controller. I have updated my question please see it.